# Why doesn't Ionic update my list when I delete items from the search bar?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

i am trying to create a search bar for my list using ionic 4. For this I have looked at the following tutorial: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/?utm_content=buffer50553&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

The search works fine, but when I delete letters from the search bar and the complete line then it doesn't update my list anymore.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

List-View.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ListClientServiceService } from 'src/app/services/list-client-service.service';
import { CarGroup } from 'src/build/openapi';
import { lablesHeadlines, lablesPagination  } from 'src/environments/lables';
@Pipe ({
  name : 'orderByCarGroupName'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-view',
  templateUrl: './list-view.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-view.page.scss'],
})
export class ListViewPage implements OnInit, PipeTransform {

  public searchControl: FormControl;
  carGroups: CarGroup[] = [];
  lablesHeadlines = lablesHeadlines;
  headlines = lablesHeadlines;
  lablesPagination = lablesPagination;
  cp = 1;

  constructor(private listClientService: ListClientServiceService, private router: Router) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

  }
  compare(a: any , b: any) {
    if (a.carGroupName > b.carGroupName){
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.carGroupName < b.carGroupName){
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  transform(input: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    return input.sort(this.compare);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listClientService.getAllCarGroupNamesWithId().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.carGroups = response;
        return response;
      });

      this.setFilteredItems('');
      this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(700))
      .subscribe(search => {
        this.setFilteredItems(search);
      });
  }

  openCarGroup(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail-view', { carGroupId: id }]);
  }
  filterItems(searchTerm: string) {
    return this.carGroups.filter(item => item.carGroupName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  }
  setFilteredItems(searchTerm: string) {
    this.carGroups = this.filterItems(searchTerm);
  }

}
```

Template:

```
 <ion-row>
      <ion-searchbar
        [formControl]="searchControl">
      </ion-searchbar>
    </ion-row>
```

Module:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ListViewPageRoutingModule,
    NgxPaginationModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListViewPage]
})
export class ListViewPageModule {}
```

Comment: Try to write an `async` pipe here.

Answer (score 0):

Your module.ts should be:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Your template should be:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title> Ionic Blank </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar
    [formControl]="searchControl"
    (ionChange)="onSearchInput()"
  ></ion-searchbar>
  <div *ngIf="searching" class="spinner-container">
    <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
  </div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"> {{ item.title }} </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and your ts file should be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Data } from '../../providers/data';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    searchTerm: string = '';
    searchControl: FormControl;
    items: any;
    searching: any = false;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: Data) {
        this.searchControl = new FormControl();
    }
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.setFilteredItems();
        this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
            this.searching = false;
            this.setFilteredItems();
        });
    }
    onSearchInput(){
        this.searching = true;
    }
    setFilteredItems() {
        this.items = this.dataService.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
    }
}
```

you can add the following css to look pretty:

```
.spinner-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just extended my list with Ng2SearchPipeModule and that works now.